# KVM host can't ping guest on same subnet

Tags: networking, server, kvm-virtualization

I have a server that has KVM installed and two guests installed onto that same machine. I have setup them to use the network port directly. They are online and I am even able to access my ownCloud (installed on one of the guests) remotely via port forwarding or from any other computer on the network.

My problem is that even though they are on the same subnet, I can not ssh into either guest from the host.

Host IP: 10.1.10.220
ownCloud Guest: 10.1.10.221
Guest 2: 10.1.10.222

```
    ping -c 2 10.1.10.221
PING 10.1.10.221 (10.1.10.221) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.1.10.220 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.1.10.220 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I know this may be a dumb question, but it needs to be asked first, is OpenSSH installed on both the VMs?

Comment: I can't blame you for asking, yes it is installed. I can ssh into all of the machines from any other computer on the network, but the host has become my vector of entry into the network from remote and now I can't ssh. It wasn't a problem during setup because I was on that network.

Comment: OK, so let me see if I understand you... If you are on the network 10.0.10.22X you can ssh the clients and the host...But now you are not on that network?  Are you in the same building?  Are you on a different subnet?

Comment: I am remote and have activated port forwarding on the modem to get 22 to forward to the host at 10.1.10.220. From there, I am trying to ssh into one of the guests at 10.1.10.221.

Comment: I am just thinking this through a bit... you are remote, are you VPNd into the network you want to control?

Comment: no, just sshing into the host and trying to then ssh into the guest from the host. I move between computers so much that VPN is not friendly to my workings.

Comment: Well, I think the problem is you are not on the same network as the machines you want to work on.  The only way to get to that network is to connect to it some how, you have set port forwarding on a router, to a machine inside of the network, but how are you connecting to that router/modem?  the internal nework you want is 10.0.x.x, but you first have to establish a connections to the router via its real IP address, once connected you can then ssh to the address inside the network, does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the answer you are looking for:

http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html

Transparent Multi-hop SSH

It is often necessary to SSH through one host to get to another host. This article will walk you through configuring SSH so that the intermediate step is transparent.
Example Network

For our example, we're going to use the network pictured below:
[image]
Example network diagram

From your computer at home you wish to log in to the host called 'tongariro' on the LAN at your office. All connections into the office LAN must pass through the firewall host 'aoraki'. The firewall host will only accept connections from the bastion host 'ruapehu'.
Doing It Manually

These are the steps we plan to automate:

To connect to 'tongariro' you must first ssh to 'ruapehu'. Because you're connecting over the internet, you'll need to specify the full domain name when you connect. You'll also want to use '-A' to enable 'agent forwarding' (discussed below):

```
ssh -A ruapehu.example.com
```

Now that you're logged in to a shell prompt on 'ruapehu', you'll need to connect to 'aoraki'. To allow password-less logins you'll have installed the public key from your home computer into the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys of each host along the way. When you execute the following command, the SSH server on 'aoraki' will request a key, this request will be forwarded back through 'ruapehu' to the agent running on your home computer and access will be granted:

```
ssh -A aoraki
```

Finally, you can connect to the target host 'tongariro':

```
ssh -A tongariro
```

Quick and Dirty Automation

The manual steps outlined above use three chained SSH connections to pass through two intermediate hosts. You can chain the three commands together into one monster command-line (perhaps in a shell script or a shell alias):

```
ssh -A -t ruapehu.example.com ssh -A -t aoraki ssh -A tongariro
```

In addition to the -A to enable agent forwarding, I've added -t to force a pseudo-tty to be allocated. Normally when your ssh command specifies a command to be run on the target host, no pseudo-tty will be allocated. That's fine if you want the command to run and then exit, but if you want an interactive shell session then you'll need a pseudo-tty.
Quick and Dirty Automation with SSHMenu

You could assign that same monster command-line to a host connection on your SSHMenu:
[image]
SSHMenu host dialog

A Better Way

Another way to automate the connections through the intermediate hosts is to add a 'ProxyCommand' setting to your SSH config file. For this to work, you must have the 'netcat' package installed on the intermediate hosts.

Start by editing your SSH config file (which might not exist yet):

```
gedit ~/.ssh/config
```

And add the following lines:

```
Host ruapehu
  HostName ruapehu.example.com

Host aoraki
  ProxyCommand ssh -q ruapehu nc -q0 aoraki 22

Host tongariro
  ProxyCommand ssh -q aoraki nc -q0 %h 22
```

The first entry defines a hostname alias so that you can ssh to 'ruapehu' instead of having to type 'ruapehu.example.com'.

The second entry sets up a proxy command that will be used to connect to the 'aoraki' host. Normally ssh establishes its own TCP connection to port 22 on the target host, but with this setting in place it will use the proxy command to establish the connection. The proxy command in the example will establish a normal SSH connection to the intermediate host ('ruapehu') and then use the 'nc' command to extend the connection to port 22 on 'aoraki'.

Now that the proxy command is set up, you can connect to the 'aoraki' host simply by typing:

```
ssh aoraki
```

The third entry builds on this by using the newly accessible 'aoraki' host in a proxy command which extends the connection to our ultimate target 'tongariro'. Note that in this command, '%h' was used for the hostname. This is simply a shorthand that tells SSH to insert the target hostname (from the line above) in place of the %h. If you want to connect to other hosts on the office LAN you can duplicate the last two lines and just change the hostname in one place.
So Why is this Better?

With the above configuration in place, you can now SSH directly to the 'tongariro' host with this command:

```
ssh tongariro
```

You can copy files directly to (or from) 'tongariro' without having to worry about intermediate steps:

```
scp path/to/local/file tongariro:path/to/remote/file
```

You can enable X-forwarding which means that any GUI program you start on 'tongariro' will display on your workstation:

```
ssh -X tongariro xclock
```

GUI application performance will be sluggish over slow network connections but some GUI apps on your local machine will now be able to use SSH to talk to the remote host. For example if you're running GNOME, you can use an 'ssh' URL in Nautilus to browse files on the remote host. (KDE provides equivalent functionality):
[image]
SSHMenu host dialog

If you right click a file and select "Open with Text Editor", the GNOME Text Editor program will run on your local machine but will use SSH to read/write the file to the remote host.

For an even more powerful approach to editing files over an SSH connection, you might like to look into bcvi.

Many other familiar tools will also be able to use the transparent SSH connections. For example you can access version control repositories (CVS, Subversion, Git etc) over SSH. You can also use port-forwarding on the SSH conection to access intranet servers or HTTP proxies on the office LAN from your workstation.
Reusing Connections

The transparent multi-hop connections can be very useful but you may find that it takes a second or two to establish each connection. This delay can become annoying if it happens a lot (e.g.: every time you save a file from the text editor).

The good news is that if you can configure SSH to reuse an existing connection. This means that for example if you have an SSH shell session running then a new connection for SCP can skip the connection setup phase. Two steps are required:

First, you must create a directory (or 'folder') which SSH will use to keep track of established connections:

```
mkdir ~/.ssh/tmp
```

Next, add these two lines at the start of your ~/.ssh/config (make sure to use your username in place of 'YOUR-NAME'):

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath   /home/YOUR-NAME/.ssh/tmp/%h_%p_%r
```

As you can see, a small investment in time setting up your SSH configuration can pay back dividends in convenience.

Comment: My problem is that the host can't see/ping/ssh to the next hop (the guest). If I were to travel to the location and get on the network my computer could see it and I can use the services on it, but I can't get host to see guest.

Comment: Did you see the answer, it is pretty complicated, what you want to do, but I think this answer is your answer. It will walk you through the steps.

Comment: This isn't working. It has to be because the host can't even ping the guest. This is trying to connect to the guest through the host and the host can't see the guest.

Comment: I would agree with you.  but you said that when on the actual network you can ssh the host and guests correct?  My next question is how did you set up the networking on the guests?  I will assume bridged, and not NAT, because I assume you assigned each a static IP?

Comment: It is via bridge to eth0 and I am having the router give out the IP based on MAC.

Comment: The best test here is to be at the actual keyboard of the host, and ping the guests, that is how I would start troubleshooting this.  you need to remove layers of the problem.  If from the actual keyboard of the host you can ping the guests then you would know the problem is ssh.  Then we can maybe find an answer to that problem first.

Comment: Maybe this thread will help...  http://superuser.com/questions/349253/guest-and-host-cannot-see-each-other-using-linux-kvm-and-macvtap  the last answer maybe the answer for you "virt-manager says explictly that macvtap does not work for host to guest network communications when you set it up. I simply added a second nat based interface, set it up in the guest, and use that to communicate with my host. "

Comment: That looks like it, I will test it and post on the results.

Comment: Sheesh, this has to be the most sophisticated answer to a question that got no upvotes for the q or a.